Revit floorplan view PDF print using Design Automation API
I developed a Revit plugin that uses floorplan view as a PDF background.
Using SubmitPrint method and PrintManager configuration, views could be printed as PDFs with PDF995/Adobe Acrobat virtual printer drivers that used as a background in Xyicon application.
using (var tr = new Transaction(document, "Xyicon printer settings creation"))
{
    tr.Start();
    document.PrintManager.SelectNewPrintDriver(printer);

    var printManager = document.PrintManager;
    printManager.PrintRange = PrintRange.Select;
    ViewSheetSetting viewSheetSetting = printManager.ViewSheetSetting;
    viewSheetSetting.CurrentViewSheetSet.Views = viewSet;
    viewSheetSetting.SaveAs("Xyicon_ViewSet");
    PaperSize paperSize = null;
    foreach (PaperSize ps in printManager.PaperSizes)
    {
        if (ps.Name.Equals("ARCH E"))
        {
            paperSize = ps;
            break;
        }
    }
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.PaperSize = paperSize;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.PaperPlacement = PaperPlacementType.Center;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.ZoomType = ZoomType.FitToPage;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.PageOrientation = PageOrientationType.Landscape;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.HiddenLineViews = HiddenLineViewsType.VectorProcessing;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.RasterQuality = RasterQualityType.High;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.ColorDepth = ColorDepthType.GrayScale;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.HideCropBoundaries = false;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.HideReforWorkPlanes = false;
    printManager.PrintSetup.CurrentPrintSetting.PrintParameters.HideUnreferencedViewTags = false;

    printManager.PrintToFileName = viewPdfFilePath;
    printManager.PrintToFile = true;

    printManager.Apply();
    printManager.PrintSetup.SaveAs("Xyicon_PinterSettings");
    tr.Commit();
}

using (var tr = new Transaction(document, "Print selected view"))
{
    tr.Start();

    var printManager = document.PrintManager;
    if (elementIdListToHide.Count != 0)
        view.HideElementsTemporary(elementIdListToHide);

    document.Regenerate();
    printManager.SubmitPrint();

    while (!IsPDFHeaderExists(viewPdfFilePath))
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

    tr.Commit();
}

Recently we decided to move plugin development at APS (Autodesk Platform Services) and integrate with Xyicon, but faced with the critical view print issue. APS doesn't have ability to print a floorplan for Revit 2021 and older versions (our users still use older versions like 2020 and 2019).
In a newest Revit versions there is a PDFExport that allows us to make a PDF, but it won't work with old versions.
I thought about couple ways of implementation:

upgrade older versions to newer version during APS WorkItem progress (it takes a lot of time for upgrade, especially with a big number of linked files)
install virtual printer on APS servers (not sure if this is possible)
use DWG export, to export view floorplan to DWG and use AutoCAD's "DWG to PDF.pc3" printer for PDF creation (takes a lot of time and token values to move output file to a different buckets)
use ForgeViewer (doesn't work with 2D floorplans - 3D only)

Is there any solution for this?

Yes, I am afraid I cannot suggest more than the options you already list. I am pretty sure that you cannot install your own virtual printer on the APS server. So, upgrading the RVT file version to a newer release or printing to some other file format are probably the most feasible options. Sorry for the bad news.

Thanks for your answer. Feels like to use AutoCAD format is the best solution in this case.

Well, best and best... what are your criteria? Myself, I very much favour open, non-proprietary file formats...

In my case the most important criteria it is a speed and stability. I wanted to export Revit file to DXF (because its open file format and it could be handled by a lot of online software), but I've had a problem of huge file size. Revit project was about 12Gb (with all the links included) and DXF (from 2D view) file size was about 140Mb, DWG was about 12Mb tho.. Non of online tools couldnt handle 140Mb file size, and I still need PDF from that.

Also, I've tried to create an SVG file from the view, but all view's element Geometry analyzation takes, literally ages and sometimes families contour is not closed, that makes wrong/corrupted shape.

You can upgrade Revit files to newer versions using Design Automation API, then you can generate PDF for the views using Model Derivative API:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/advanced-option-rvtdwg-2d-views-svf2-post-job

Yeah, I already tried this approach. With small Revit files it works pretty well. The main issue, huge Revit project with a number of links, takes a very long time to upgrade, I've tried 12Gb Revit project (with 8 link files), approximately it took about 6 hours to upgrade.
