Design Automation for AutoCAD work item throws an error during file open
Using Design Automation I need to open all *.dwg files from folder and print PDF from Model space.
When I test it locally it works perfect, but in a cloud WorkItem stops to work when DocumentManager tries to open any extracted file.
This is part where WorkItem breaks:
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(extractZipFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".dwg"));
foreach (var file in files)
{
   var openedDocument = AcadApp.DocumentManager.Open(file, false);
   manager.MdiActiveDocument = openedDocument;
   var openedDatabase = openedDocument.Database;
   //Work with opened document...
   openedDocument.CloseAndDiscard();
}

And Work Item result looks like this:
[07/01/2024 15:29:27] Folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\acad_output" has been created.
[07/01/2024 15:29:27] Starting work item 80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d
[07/01/2024 15:29:27] Start download phase.
[07/01/2024 15:29:27] Start downloading input: verb - 'Get', url - 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/a30ef8a9-f959-4e77-bd07-74febaf9e92c.dwg'
[07/01/2024 15:29:27] Start downloading input: verb - 'Get', url - 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:xyicon_bucket/output.json'
[07/01/2024 15:29:27] Start downloading input: verb - 'Get', url - 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:xyicon_bucket/revit_output_.zip'
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] End downloading file. Source=urn:adsk.objects:os.object:xyicon_bucket/output.json,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\inputFile.json,BytesDownloaded=1570,Duration=334ms
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] End downloading file. Source=urn:adsk.objects:os.object:xyicon_bucket/revit_output_.zip,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\acad_input.zip,BytesDownloaded=46107,Duration=330ms
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] End downloading file. Source=urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/a30ef8a9-f959-4e77-bd07-74febaf9e92c.dwg,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\Input.dwg,BytesDownloaded=32467,Duration=373ms
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] End download phase successfully.
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\Input.dwg" "T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\inputFile.json" "T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\acad_input.zip" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\29782f183477c2a1b4b98b6a2426b474.XyiconApp.AutoCADPrintApp[1].package" /s "T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\setting_script.scr"]
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Start script phase.
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Start AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\tmp\accc1762).
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright 2023 Autodesk, Inc.  All rights reserved. (U.61.Z.187)
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Execution Path:
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] T:\Aces\AcesRoot\24.3\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Current Directory: T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Isolating to regkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d\userdata.
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] Version Number: U.61.Z.187 (UNICODE)
[07/01/2024 15:29:28] LogFilePath has been set to the working folder.
[07/01/2024 15:29:29] Regenerating model.
[07/01/2024 15:29:29] AutoCAD menu utilities loaded.
[07/01/2024 15:29:29] Command:
[07/01/2024 15:29:29] Command:
[07/01/2024 15:29:29] Command:
[07/01/2024 15:29:29] Command: (command "DWGTOPDF")
[07/01/2024 15:29:32] End AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[07/01/2024 15:29:32] Error: Application accoreconsole.exe exits with code 1 which indicates an error.
[07/01/2024 15:29:32] End script phase.
[07/01/2024 15:29:32] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[07/01/2024 15:29:32] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[07/01/2024 15:29:32] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "activityId": "XyiconApp.AutoCADPrintAppActivity+dev",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2024-07-01T15:29:27.5198543Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2024-07-01T15:29:27.6941103Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2024-07-01T15:29:28.129703Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2024-07-01T15:29:32.5634556Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 80144
  },
  "id": "80b1dc931698465caca7dd33f3f1038d"
}

Unfortunately, there is no any kind of errors handling for AutoCAD (always show 'Application accoreconsole.exe exits with code 1 which indicates an error.'), I can't see why the application is broken, is there a way to find minimal error description?


I can't see why the application is broken, is there a way to find minimal error description?

You could wrap your code with try/catch and print out more details. Otherwise, the exception propagates causes accoreconsole.exe to crash.
BTW, I don't recommend that you loop through drawings like this. I would recommend that you create a workitem for each dwg so that they can be executed in parallel.

Yeah, sure, I do have try/catch from the very beginning of the function, but the code doesn't even start to run if there is  AcadApp.DocumentManager.Open(file, false) line.
Well what I am trying to achieve, is described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78509606/revit-floorplan-view-pdf-print-using-design-automation-api
I start Revit WorkItem, it returns me zip file of the *.dwg located in the bucket, I can get it and with one Acad WorkItem print all of them. The number of *.dwg could be very different, not sure that it would be good solution to create WorkItem for each.

It would be a much better solution to create a workitem for each: it will be faster; it will be more fault tolerant.

in my case try-catch is completely ignored and nothing is logged, execution crashes immediately regardless right after command is called and in logs there is no exception logged

I would add logging to console which will go to automation report between every line to see whether error is caused by opening the document or closing and discarding it. Also I would add logging of what file path is going in. In my case CloseAndDiscard method was throwing an error even locally.

For some reason System.Console.WriteLine just doesn't work for me, I've used it for Design Automation for Revit and it worked. I create logging file for that where I write code actions.
The problem is that code don't even start if there is AcadApp.DocumentManager.Open(file, false) this line in the code, so logging won't work.

Meanwhile prepared simple code to test loop files opening
 static public void LoopTest()
 {
     foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".dwg")))
     {
         var openedDocument = AcadApp.DocumentManager.Open(file, false);
         var openedDatabase = openedDocument.Database;
         openedDocument.CloseAndDiscard();
     }
 }```
Ran it on AutoCAD2024 (R24.3), files just open and close, without any errors.

You can always log to your own txt file and return it as output parameter if nothing else

I would also assume that in cloud the paths migh be diferent, spaces in file names might behave differently than in your local file system or you might not have write permission when extracting files if you are transfering them to workitem via input parameter, that is why logging is so crucial for troubleshooting

System.Console.WriteLine doesn't work because we try to guide your towards Editor.WriteMessage. The reason we try to guide towards it because Editor.WriteMessage works in all 3 places where it matters: AutoCAD, local coreconsole and DA. System.Console.WriteLine doesn't work in AutoCAD because AutoCAD is a Windows app so there's no console.
